# How can I insert tab in list items with Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm generating pdf documents with Freemarker. I need to insert tabs in list between the list items. My recourse is a JSON file.
I'm using the right_pad function, but it seems like it doesn't do anything. Any idea how to do this?

```
<#list data.house as house>
    <br>${"House name:"?right_pad(125)} ${house.name!}</br>
        <#list data.properties as properties>
            <br>${"Value:"?right_pad(125)} ${properties.value!} HUF</br>
            <br>${"Bank account number:"?right_pad(125)} ${properties.bankAccountNumber!}</br>
</#list>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [right_pad](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_right_pad) builtin is adding whitespaces at the end of the string, but [your browser don't display these whitespaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace).

One solution is to use CSS for the layout of your information. There are several way to do it, here is one of them:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        span{float: left; width: 200px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<#list data.house as house>
    <span>House name:</span>${house.name!}<br />
</#list>
</body>
</html>
```